# Javascript, Can I get to another functions child

Tags: javascript, parent-child, nested

here is an example.

```
    function parentOne(){
        //do something

       function ChildOne(){
        // do something
       };
    };

    function parentTwo(){
       //how can I input data into ChildOne() from here?
    };
```

I am trying to fix a bug. ParentTwo will only work once childOne has been hit. Thats because when childOne is hit in my code it starts the direction API. After that I can use parentTwo to change the to or from value in my form and it will submit. Its kinda hard to explain but I need parentTwo to init childOne if the user didnt do it through the parentOne function first.

I know javascript but I have never tried this before and if seems kinda fishy to me.

Comment: Um, the current way it is written, it is impossible.

Comment: `parentOne` must be called before `parentTwo` can access `ChildOne`.

Comment: parentOne is called on an onload event. How could I lay this out so  it might be possible? This app is like ready to go I just ran into this bug and its stopping deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call ParentOne a factory that creates a function (ChildOne). But you'd need to rewrite it a little.

```
function parentOne(){
  //do something

  return function ChildOne(){
    // do something
    return 'x';
  };
};

function parentTwo(){
  //how can I input data into ChildOne() from here?
  var a = parentOne();

  //You can call a() now. It runs the returned function which is ChildOne
  var b = a();

  //b is now the result of ChildOne, which is 'x'
};
```

Comment: Great solution! This ended do what I needed thank you Christian!

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to return ChildOne from parentOne. The benefit of this is your existing code that makes use of parentOne and childOne shouldn't need to be altered.

If you need a condition then you can store a variable to say whether or not ChildOne has already been called.

```
var childOneCalled = false;

function parentOne(){
    //do something

   function ChildOne(){
    // do something
    childOneCalled = true;
   };

   return ChildOne();
};

function parentTwo(){
   if(!childOneCalled){
       parentOne()(); // call ChildOne
   }
};
```

Comment: I used your solution and it worked for me as well! I would vote this up if I had enough rep. Thank you also!